# Как работает Windows reset?

Tags: windows, администрирование, windows-11

Где хранится состояние, к которому система откатывается при нажатии ресет в настройках? Хочу переписать его с моими текущими настройками, чтобы в случае ресета не надо было заново настраивать.

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос, скорее всего Вам нужен реестр Windows команда `regedit` там все настройки включая по-умолчанию, можно экспортировать и импортировать, но целиком не советую (будет огромный файл) Конечно реестр не единственное место настроек, но наиболее стандартное.

Comment: @DaniilLoban это частично поможет, да. Но я хочу чтобы в настройках при нажатии reset (он же откат к "первоначальному" состоянию системы) у меня откатывало на мой образ, а не на тот, который зашит там сейчас (где?)

Comment: Думаю, даже если найти путь и образ, не получится заменить на свое, иначе все бы так делали) Надежнее пользоваться утилитами для бэкапов диска

Comment: Я бы тебе советовал посмотреть в сторону `CloneZilla`. Сжимать винду лучше всего на уровне разделов, а не веток реестра и файликов в appdata.